# Getting public feed from multiple Facebook Groups via Graph API 2.3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We're building an app where the user will login and allow us to read their public posts that they share in a set of groups that we administer. With API 2.3 I can see that facebook lets us read the public feed of a group but from 2.4 on wards, only Admin posts are readable. From what I have gathered, Facebook is going to let us use the 2.3 API until June 2017, which is perfect. But they're not allowing a new account or an existing one to create a new app in 2.3, they're imposing 2.5 on everyone.

1. Will we be able to read all public feed (user will allow) from a set of groups that we administer?
2. Can a new account create an app under API 2.3?
3. How long will it work until 2.3 is completely phased out?
4. If not a set a groups, can we read public feed from a single group that we administer?

I know that we have to submit the app for review but we need to confirm this before we start building.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try with a User Token of a group admin. In general, you are not supposed to read the feed of a group you don´t manage.
2. No, new Apps will only be able to use the latest API version as minimum.
3. Check out the changelog to find out how long 2.3 will work (July 8, 2017): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
4. See 1

You do not have to submit your App if you only use the User Token of a group admin. The admin just needs to have a role in the App.

Comment: What If I manage to get hands on an old app created long back on api 2.3 and I change all of its settings to the new app? Will it work?

Comment: what for? 2.3 will be gone in less than a year, it would be pointless to build something on an API that is deprecated.

Comment: btw, if you manage the group anyway, where´s the problem? just use user_managed_groups and you will get access to all groups you manage. it´s not something that disappeared with v2.3. user_groups itself is gone forever, you can´t even use it in an older app anymore (90-days-deprecation).